# How to work with multiple schemas with Liquibase

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration, liquibase

My new company's database use multiple schemas. Each schema has the same table structure.

Currently, when we want to run a SQL query, we have to run that for each schema manually.

After some research, I found Liquibase is a good candidate to automate our process.

After doing some tutorials on the Liquibase website I can use Liquibase for the databases with only one schema. If I want to use multiple schemas I have to run `liquibase update` command for every schema it seems.

Even though there's this `---schemas=<schema1, schema2>` parameter, it doesn't work in my case.

Please let me know if anyone knows how to do this. And let me know if there are any further information need to have a good idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

in Postgresql , I set at the beginning of script as schema that I need to run the change in

set search_path=schema1
.. sql code ...

Does that help?

Please also feel free to ask question in Liquibase forums at https://forum.liquibase.org/  for better reach and possible quicker solution